# isNumber or isObject is not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to loop though elements which could be numeric or object. I am trying to use condition to display number or another sub ng-repeat. Following an example of code

```html
 <tr  ng-repeat="(key,val) in vm.data">
   <td>{{key}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="y in val">
      <span ng-if="angular.isNumber(y)">{{y}}</span>
                                
       <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="(a,b) in y"><td>{{a}}</td><td>{{b}}</td></tr>
      </table>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I am very new to angular. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like the below code, also please check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fAWYQW36RQjMRuNNloSO?p=preview) for working example.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.isNumber = angular.isNumber;
```

**Template:**

```
<span ng-if="isNumber(value)">Valid Number</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the angular.isNumber function to a function in your controller.

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("vmCtrl", function () {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.isNumber = angular.isNumber;
  
  vm.data = {
    "thing1": [1,2,3,4],
    "thing2": [{
      "something1a": "something1b",
      "something2a": "something2b"
    },
    {
      "somethingElse1a": "somethingElse1b",
      "somethingElse2a": "somethingElse2b"
    }]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="App" ng-controller="vmCtrl as vm">
  <tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in vm.data">
     <td>{{key}}</td>
     <td ng-repeat="y in val">
        <span ng-if="vm.isNumber(y)">{{y}}</span>

         <table>
           <tr ng-repeat="(a,b) in y"><td>{{a}}</td><td>{{b}}</td></tr>
         </table>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```